# How to fetch photos only from local library, not optimized by iCloud

Tags: swift

I want to fetch photos only from local library and show them in collection view. I have turned on "optimized photos" in iCloud settings so some of my photos are stored in iCloud. This is how I fetch assets:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)
        
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection[0], options: fetchOptions)
```

The problem is that I don't want to fetch all my photos. I just want all that don't have to be downloaded. I thought that subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary will do the job, but it still fetches all photos.